# Como comparar o valor de um HashMap<chave, valor> com uma váriavel?

Tags: java, hashmap, iterator

Tenho um `HashMap aluno<Integer, Float>`, onde a chave `Integer` será o número de matrícula do aluno, e o valor `Float` será a nota do aluno.

Consegui a média das notas utilizando o `Iterator`, mas agora preciso saber quais alunos têm a nota acima da média e não consegui fazer utilizando o símbolo `>`

segue o código:

```
  HashMap<Integer, Float> aluno = new HashMap<Integer Float>();
  .
  .
  .
  //achei soma das notas
  Iterator<Integer> i = aluno.keySet().iterator();
  while(i.hasNext()){
      int chave = i.next();
      sumNotas+=aluno.get(chave);
  }

  //printei média
  //n é a quantidde de alunos
  System.out.println("média: " + sumNotas/n + "\n" + "Alunos acima da média:" + "\n");

  //quero printar se a nota do aluno é maior que a média, mas não funciona
  //n é a quantidde de alunos
  while(i.hasNext()){
    int chave = i.next();
    if(aluno.get(chave) > sumNotas/n)
        System.out.print(chave +  ", ");
    }
```

Comment: Tens de começar o iterator de novo porque no segundo while o iterator está no fim do HasMap

Comment: @JorgeB. ja faz logo uma resposta

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 5):

Não funciona porque tens de começar o `Iterator` de novo porque no segundo `while` o `Iterator` está no fim do `HashMap`:

```
//quero printar se a nota do aluno é maior que a média, mas não funciona
//n é a quantidde de alunos

i = aluno.keySet().iterator();
while(i.hasNext()){
    int chave = i.next();
    if(aluno.get(chave) > sumNotas/n)
        System.out.print(chave +  ", ");
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Primeiro: você sabe porque escolheu o [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)? Sabe que ele não tem ordem alguma definida? Que você não terá os alunos por ordem de matrícula? Isto resolve o que você precisa?

Seu problema é que para varrer todo o mapa é feito através de um iterador que nada mais é que um meio de saber onde você está em uma coleção de dados. Ele sabe onde você está posicionado na coleção. E claro, uma dessas coleções é o `HashMap`. Se você navega por toda a coleção, o que acontece quando tenta navegar nela com o mesmo iterador? Ele não consegue. Ela considera que já terminou, não tem mais nada o que ver ali.

Podemos dizer a grosso modo que o iterador é um objeto que guarda a variável de um *loop* (claro que ele é mais que isto) e cada vez vez que vai para o próximo elemento ele é incrementado.

Então a solução é reiniciar o iterador. Como o iterador do Java não permite fazer isto diretamente, temos que começar um novo iterador. Seria algo assim:

```
HashMap<Integer, Float> aluno = new HashMap<Integer Float>();
  .
  .
  .
  //achei soma das notas
  Iterator<Integer> i = aluno.keySet().iterator();
  while(i.hasNext()){
      int chave = i.next();
      sumNotas+=aluno.get(chave);
  }

  //printei média
  //n é a quantidde de alunos
  System.out.println("média: " + sumNotas/n + "\n" + "Alunos acima da média:" + "\n");

  //quero printar se a nota do aluno é maior que a média, mas não funciona
  //n é a quantidde de alunos
  i = aluno.keySet().iterator(); //<============ adicionado aqui
  while(i.hasNext()){
    int chave = i.next();
    if(aluno.get(chave) > sumNotas/n)
        System.out.print(chave +  ", ");
    }
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Collections/HashMapExample.java).

Comment: Já vem atrasado :P